# UIView.transitionWithView not animating

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to animate the change of an image in a UIImageView using `transitionWithVIew`. The image changes, but it doesn't seem to be animating. Not sure why this is happening.

Here's my code:

```
func changeBackgroundAtIndex(index : Int) {
        switch index {
        case 0:
            animateChangeWithImage(MLStyleKit.imageOfAboutMe)
        case 1:
            animateChangeWithImage(MLStyleKit.imageOfProjects)
        case 2:
            animateChangeWithImage(MLStyleKit.imageOfSkills)
        case 3:
            animateChangeWithImage(MLStyleKit.imageOfEducation)
        case 4:
            animateChangeWithImage(MLStyleKit.imageOfTheFuture)
        default:
            animateChangeWithImage(MLStyleKit.imageOfAboutMe)
        }
    }

    func animateChangeWithImage(image : UIImage) {
        UIView.transitionWithView(backgroundImageView, duration: 0.4, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.backgroundImageView.image = image
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: this function works properly with self.view.

Comment: Refer this another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616655/uiview-transitionwithview-doesnt-work

Comment: @Rahul Using `self.View` instead of `self.backgroundImageView` isnt fixing it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with `index`. I was getting the `index` as the uses was scrolling through a scroll view, which would constantly keep updating the `index` variable and not give it enough time to actually animate.

Putting `changeBackgroundAtIndex` inside `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` instead of `scrollViewDidScroll` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function signature to this, where you take both the image you want to change and the UIImageView itself. 
    `func animateChangeWithImage(image: UIImage, inImageView: UIImageView)`

Comment: Tried that - it didn't fix it :/.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the actual image itself is not animated when changed given that it is not a UIView.

This would seem to do what you want: [How to animate the change of image in an UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834573/how-to-animate-the-change-of-image-in-an-uiimageview)