# UIView transitionWithView not working first time only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, nstimer

I'm making a slideshow using `UIImageView` and `NSTimer`. Everything is working fine except that for the first time when `transitionWithView` method is called, the animation DOESN'T happen, it just changes the image without cross-dissolve, and after that, the cross dissolve works at every image change.

Please can you find the error in my code:

```
-(void) startSlideShow
{

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrImageLinks objectAtIndex:currentImage]];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                      duration:1.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{

                        [manager downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                                              options:0
                                             progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

                                             }
                                            completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                                if (image) {

                                                    [self.imageView setImage:image];
                                                }
                                            }];
                    } completion:nil];

timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}
```

Here's the `handleTimer` code :

```
- (void) handleTimer: (NSTimer *) timer {

    currentImage++;
    if ( currentImage >= self.arrImageLinks.count )
        currentImage = 0;


    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrImageLinks objectAtIndex:currentImage]]; 

[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                          duration:1.0f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:^{

                            [manager downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                                                  options:0
                                                 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

                                                 }
                                                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                                    if (image) {

                                                        [self.imageView setImage:image];
                                                    }
                                                }];
                        } completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616655/uiview-transitionwithview-doesnt-work?rq=1. It might help you.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I have the same issue, where it only works first time.

Comment: @gizmodo I don't remember if I got it working or not, but I started using [this](https://github.com/kirualex/KASlideShow) awesome slideshow library which let us create slideshows easily. Go check it if u want to implement image slideshows.

Comment: Hello I have similar issue can you find anything ?

Comment: @YogeshPatel Please check my comment above. I used KASlideShow library and it served the purpose.

Comment: Okay Thanks will check and inform you